# Get computers not in a specified group

Tags: powershell

I have tried this a few different ways and for some reason it continues to give me the computers that are in the specified group and can't seem to figure out why.

```
$Windows_10_Computers_GPO = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -eq "Windows 10 Pro"' -SearchBase "OU=site,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -notlike "*site-DG-Windows_10*" }
```

The above code returns all computers that are Windows 10 and in the group. Not what is expected. So then I tried the below code and the same result.

```
$Windows_10_Computers_GPO = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -eq "Windows 10 Pro"' -SearchBase "OU=site,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" -Properties MemberOf

Foreach ($Computer in $Windows_10_Computers_GPO) {
    if ($Computer.MemberOf -notlike "*site-DG-Windows_10*") {
        $Email_Body = $Email_Body + $Computer.Name + "<br>"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity site-DG-Windows_10 -Members $Computer | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Essentially I am attempting to find all Windows 10 Pro computers in a specific OU and add them to a specific group if they are not in that group.

Comment: `-notcontains` instead of `-notlike`, possibly may be the whole issue, here.   However, remove the wildcards `*` as well. Try it, and let us know?

Comment: Removing wildcard resulted in the same thing. -notcontains again same result. It makes no sense :(

Answer (score 0):

Have'nt tested should work

```
$Windows_10_Computers_GPO = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -eq "Windows 10 Pro"' -SearchBase "OU=site,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" | where {$.memberof -notContains 'site-DG-Windows_10'} | Format-Table Name
Foreach ($Computer in $Windows_10_Computers_GPO) {
        $Email_Body = $Email_Body + $Computer.Name + "<br>"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "site-DG-Windows_10"
    }
```

If dont wanna add email body straight add

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -eq "Windows 10 Pro"' -SearchBase "OU=site,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object { $_.memberOf -notcontains 'site-DG-Windows_10' } | Add-ADGroupMember "site-DG-Windows_10"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being having the variable on the wrong side.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -eq "Windows 10 Pro"' -SearchBase "OU=site,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object { "CN=site-DG-Windows_10,OU=GPOs,OU=Groups,OU=site,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" -NotIn $_.memberof } | Select Name,Memberof
```

This ended up